# Loop through html table (for each tr)

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop, html-table

I need to be able to loop through an HTML table and output data.  In each `<tr>` there is 8 `td`'s.  The first `td` is a dropdown menu of engineers.  The next 7 `td`s are days of the week with drop downs for time slots.

I'm basically building a scheduler output for a specific internal app.  (that's irrelevant here).

So, here's an example table:

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Engineer</th>
    <th scope="col">Monday</th>
    <th scope="col">Tuesday</th>
    <th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
    <th scope="col">Thursday</th>
    <th scope="col">Friday</th>
    <th scope="col">Saturday</th>
    <th scope="col">Sunday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Each `td` has a form element and each `tr` is a "section" of data.  In the end I will have 20+ `tr`'s and need to be able to run through each `tr` and grab the relavant data from these, however, I need to be able to iterate through each `tr` so that I can manage the code better.

Is there a way to do this with PHP?

Comment: Maybe this site will [help](http://www.onderstekop.nl/articles/114/)

Comment: I don't exactly want to rely on someone else's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<table width="100%" border="0"><tr>';
echo '<td width="20px"></td>';
echo '<td align="left"><strong>Title</strong></td>';
echo '<td align="center" width="125px"><strong>Posted</strong></td>';

$sql    = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `announcement` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT '.$search['start'].', '.$search['max'];
$rows   = $mysql_conn->fetch_array($sql);

foreach($rows as $key=>$record) {
    echo (($key+1)%2) ? '<tr bgcolor="#AEDEFF" >' : '<tr>';
    echo '<td align="left"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="delete[]" id="delete[]" value="'.$record["id"].'" /></td>';
    echo '<td align="left"><a href="?page=cpanel&amp;module=announcement&amp;task=edit&amp;id='.$record["id"].'">'. $record["title"] .'</a></td>';
    echo '<td align="center">'.$record["datetime"].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Example of what I use when I want to output a list of rows with columns of data. Not sure if this is what you want but it works. :)

Comment: While I'm not doing any MySQL processing, the `foreach($rows as $key=>$record)` concept is what I went with; thanks.

Comment: echo (($key+1)%2) ? '<tr bgcolor="#AEDEFF" >' : '<tr>'; just changes the odd line to a different color for viewing :)